# list item selection-how to display a tick image on the selected item in the list box

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, listbox

I have a list box and i have to display a tick mark on the item selected.I tried this code

### List Box

```
 <ListBox Height="691" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="listBox1" Margin="-12,71,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="480" SelectionChanged="listBox1_SelectionChanged">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderThickness="0,1,0,0" BorderBrush="#FFC1BCBC" Width="490">
                        <Grid Height="70">
                            <TextBlock
                            Name="clients"
                            Margin="10,12,0,0"
                            Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="24" FontWeight="SemiBold" Foreground="Black"></TextBlock>
                            <Image Height="30" Width="30"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                           Name="imageTick" 
                           Stretch="Fill" 
                           VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                           Source="{Binding strAccountSelectedTickPath}"
                           Margin="380,0,0,0" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

### xaml.cs

```
 private void listBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        string clientId="";

        if (listBox_1.SelectedIndex >= 0)
        {



            (Application.Current as App).obj_subnodes = newlist[listBox1.SelectedIndex];
            if ((Application.Current as App).obj_subnodes.strAccountSelectedTickPath==""||(Application.Current as App).obj_subnodes.strAccountSelectedTickPath==null)
            {

                    if ( (Application.Current as App).obj_subnodes.strAccountSelectedTickPath = "")
                    {

                         (Application.Current as App).obj_subnodes.strAccountSelectedTickPath = "/sprinklr;component/Images/IsSelected.png";}
else{ (Application.Current as App).obj_subnodes.strAccountSelectedTickPath = ""; }
                initializeListBox();
            }
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Home.xaml, UriKind.Relative));
        }
    }
 private void initializeListBox()
    {
        listBox1.ItemsSource = "";
        listBox1.ItemsSource = newlist;
    }
```

but the problem is suppose ifi have two items in list box say item1 and item2 and at first time i selected item1 and the tick mark displayed on item1 and after that i selected item 2 and the tick marlk displayed on item2 .but the tick mark on item1 doesnot gone.I have to display one tick mark to indicate the selected item,that is i want the tick image to display on the item i clicked.Is there any solution for this.and is there any option to get controll access for the tick image inside the list box.if there is an option i can use imagetick.visibility=visibility.collapsed.but i dont find such an option.is there any solution for this please help me

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achieve this is to change the style / template of the `ListBoxItem` so that when it is in the 'selected' state, a tick image is displayed.

You need to create a `Style` that sets the `Template` for `ListBoxItem`, adding your tick image within each item. For details of how to do this, see the [following blog post](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/How-to-customize-the-WP7-ListBox-Selected-Item--Part1-Control-Template). You can apply this style to your `ListBox` by setting the `ItemContainerStyle`.

To turn the tick mark on / off based on selection, you will need to add a `VisualState` to your `ListBoxItem` Template, which is described in [this blog post](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/How-to-customize-the-WP7-ListBox-Selected-Item--Part2-Visual-States).

Answer (score 1):

Download the latest [Silverlight Toolkit for Windows Phone](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/) (or install it via NuGet) and use the `MultiselectList` instead of a regular `ListBox`. The MultiselectList supports checkboxes designed to match the functionality of the mail client.